# Running a java method from console, using and already inputted method

Tags: java, command, line

I'd like to write a method that is executable from the console

Say for instance I have a class "Plus" that adds 3 to an int "i". I'm supposed to be able to run the program from the console as follows:

$ java Plus 7
10

basically I want to read the value after "Plus" as the int "i" a

I can't find any documentation on the subject, but I wasn't really sure how to search. 
It should be possible with the standard java package, since it's homework.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: a good place to start is 1) Look into the main method and parameters it takes, namely, the args[] array. This is where you'll implement the logic to add 3 to some int `i` 2) Look into loops. 3) Look into executable jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is 1) Look into the main method and parameters it takes, namely, the args[] array. This is where you'll implement the logic to add 3 to some int i 2) Look into loops. 3) Look into executable jars

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jdk and JVM. Set path variable to javac present in bin folder of your jdk.
Then you can use `javac program.java` to compile and `java classpath program args` to execute.
Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: The problem isn't compiling or executing the program. I need to execute the program using a value entered after the program name. The value isn't one I enter while the program is running